# Is google play notify the user if my published apk is updated....???How to do that?

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app to Google play before 20 days and now i got 250 active users.
But now i just updated my application and i published latest version of app to Google play.
If the play store automatically updated the latest version app file to users mobile or how to notify the users to install latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play periodically reminds users to update their app is a new version compatible with their device is available.

It is entirely up to the user to actually install the update.

You can notify them by building in a notification system into your app that checks with your server to see if an update is available, and asks the user to install it if it is.

Comment: But my published app doesn't having any notification systems to notify the user to update their old version...What is my solution to open the latest app to already installed users mobile.....

Comment: Is there a way for my application to query the Marketplace application and then notify the user if a newer version is available ?

Answer (score 1):

If user has enabled notifications in Google Play settings, will receive a status-bar notification about new update, but doesn't have to install your update.

Some users have enabled Auto-WiFi-updates in Google Play settings, then your app will be automatically updated when phone will be idle.

If you have your own website you can write an announcement about very important update, necessary to correct of application.

There's no other way. You can implement autoupdate system in your app in the next version.

Comment: But my published app doesn't having any notification systems to notify the user to update their old version...What is my solution to open the latest app to already installed users mobile....

Comment: Is there a way for my application to query the Marketplace application and then notify the user if a newer version is available?

Comment: Read about Google Play API : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

Comment: Users enabled notifications and Auto-WiFi-updates in Google Play settings but they are not receives status bar notifications.....